# Return path as MVC routing parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

When I have a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/dir1/dir2/file1.txt
```

I would like the path, `/dir1/dir2/file1.txt`, passed as an argument to my controller action.

Changing my default route to this won't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FileSystem", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The slashes in the path are causing the issue, obviously, but I'm unable to URL encode them. Is there any way to tell the routing engine to grab the entire path with the slashes and pass it as the `id` to my `FileSystem` controller's `Details` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{*id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FileSystem", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Care to explain in more detail? The only difference from the OP's post is the asterisks (as far as I can tell).

Comment: If you use asterisk in last url parameter routing matches all matchet data as one parameter. For example if you have url like /customer/111/details, then route url /customer/{id} doesn't matches it at all, but /customer/{*id} matches it and passed 111/details as id value

Comment: I completely whiffed on this... I had just read an article by Mike Wasson about routing in Web API 2 and it used the wildcard mapping to pass a datetime with slashes. ref: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2